# ReactJs aggregate data from components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

what's the best way to split a big component into multiple smaller ones and aggregate their data? I would like to access the state of the BillingDataComponent, NameComponent and AddressComponent in the FormComponent.

Example:

```
var FormComponent = React.createClass({
  _onClick: function() {
    // Access child data here
    var name = ???
    var address = ???
    var billingData = ???

    ActionCreator.updateFormDataOnServer(formDataAggregatedFromChildren);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <NameComponent name="Maybe the name is already set?" />
          <AddressComponent />
          <BillingDataComponent />
          <button onClick={this._onClick} >Submit</button>
        </form>
      <div>
    );
  }
});

var NameComponent = React.createClass({  
  _onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this._onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// AddressComponent and BillingDataComponent similiar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let the `FormComponent` own the data and pass it down as props to the other components. When the data should change, the children should propagate the change up to the form:

```
var FormComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: ""
    };
  },

  _onClick: function() {
    // Access child data here
    var name = ???
    var address = ???
    var billingData = ???

    ActionCreator.updateFormDataOnServer(formDataAggregatedFromChildren);
  },

  _onNameChange: function(name) {
    this.setState({
      name: name
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <NameComponent onChange={this._onNameChange} value={this.state.name} />
          <AddressComponent />
          <BillingDataComponent />
          <button onClick={this._onClick} >Submit</button>
        </form>
      <div>
    );
  }
});

var NameComponent = React.createClass({  
  _onChange: function(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this._onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// AddressComponent and BillingDataComponent similiar
```